# CLOSED: Unable to the determine sourceType <S> and targetType <T>

Tags: spring

I have this converter to trim whitespaces

```
@Component
public class StringTrimmingConverter implements Converter<String, String> {
    @Override
    public String convert(String source) {
        return source.trim();
    }
 }
```

But I'm getting this error upon startup of the web app project...

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to the determine sourceType  and targetType  which your Converter converts between; declare these generic types.
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.addConverter(GenericConversionService.java:95)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionServiceFactory.registerConverters(ConversionServiceFactory.java:50)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(ConversionServiceFactoryBean.java:69)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    ... 21 more

Here's the configuration

```
<mvc:annotation-driven validator="validator" conversion-service="conversionService"/>

<bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="converters">
        <set>
            <bean class="ph.com.xxx.yyy.converter.StringTrimmingConverter"/>
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Could you post your spring configuration?

Comment: I updated the question and included the configuration.

Comment: Try removing `@Component`

Comment: Try using a `List` instead of a `Set` in the configuration?

Comment: I also tried that one before. It's not working. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Sorry for quickly throwing all these suggestions.  Maybe you cannot convert to the same type, have you tried swithing the converter to `Convertor<String,Integer>`? What version of `Spring` are you using?

Comment: I tried switching the converter to Converter<String, Integer>. Still, the same error.
I'm using Spring 3.1.2.RELEASE.

Comment: Do you have this project on github or anyway I could see the full source?

Comment: My project is confidential so I can't show you the source code. You think I'm missing something in the configuration?

Answer (score 0):

The bean is declared in your configuration and using annotations.  I think the `Converter` bean should only be declared once:

```
//@Component Remove this
public class StringTrimmingConverter implements Converter<String, String> {
    @Override
    public String convert(String source) {
        return source.trim();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this already by doing this instead of bean configuration in the applicationContext.

```
@Component("conversionService")
public class StringConverterService extends FormattingConversionService {
    public StringConverterService() {
        this.addConverter(new StringTrimmingConverter());
    }
}
```